# Serial monitor shows repeated CIPSEND and CIPCLOSE

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, thingspeak

I'm trying to build a heart rate monitor using ESP-01. The code compiles and uploads well but once uploaded, in the serial monitor it shows the following. It keeps repeat CIPSEND and CIPCLOSE over and over. 
What could cause this?
Could it be faulty hardware or is it a problem with the code?

```
 AT+CIPSTART="TCP","184.106.153.149",80
 AT+CIPSEND=29
 AT+CIPCLOSE
 AT+CIPSTART="TCP","184.106.153.149",80
 AT+CIPSEND=29
 AT+CIPCLOSE
 AT+CIPSTART="TCP","184.106.153.149",80
 AT+CIPSEND=29
 AT+CIPCLOSE
 AT+CIPSTART="TCP","184.106.153.149",80
```

Comment: A problem with the code.

Comment: The code is at the end of the webpage. I dont know if theres anything wrong with the code. Could it be faulty hardware?    https://www.how2electronics.com/pulse-rate-monitoring-over-internet-using-thingspeak/

Comment: the code on that web page is improperly formatted ... it is a really bad example to beginner programmers ..... i would not be surprised if it contains bugs

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you are seeing those messages on the serial monitor is because the code is *telling* it to print those messages on the serial monitor.

Every time a message is sent to the ESP8266 it is also sent (for debugging purposes) to the Serial.